# Why is $\{(x, y) \in [a, b] \times [a, b]: f(x) \geq y\}$ a Borel set?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f: I = [a, b] \rightarrow I$ is a Borel function. Why is $\{(x, y) \in [a, b] \times [a, b]: f(x) \geq y\}$ a Borel set?

Since $f$ is a Borel function, for any open set $U$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is Borel. However, I can't seem to be able to write $\{(x, y) \in [a, b] \times [a, b]: f(x) \geq y\}$ as the inverse image of an open set.

Comment: Think about it a little longer. Your idea is not off.

Comment: Not every Borel set is the inverse image of an open set. Take the case where $f$ is continuous, for example, then it is certainly Borel, but preimage of an open set is open.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:I\rightarrow I$ be a Borel function. Let $F=\{(x,y)\in I\times I: f(x)\geq y\}$. Consider the map $g:I\times I\rightarrow I$ defined by $g(x,y)=f(x)-y$. If you can show that $g$ is Borel you'll be done, for then $F=g^{-1}([0,\infty))$.

Answer (score 0):

My first approach seems have some problem.
This is second approach:

$\{(x, y) \in [a, b] \times [a, b]: f(x) \geq y\}=\{x\times (y,+\infty): f(x)\in I\}=\cup_{y\in I} f^{-1}([y,\infty))\times y$ is a closed set hence borel.

Comment: This seems to be a potentially uncountable union of Borel sets in your answer?

Comment: $f^{-1}([y,\infty))$ is a borel set in $I$. Borel set is a $\sigma-$algebra. So union of Borel set is Borel in I. Crossed by $I$ is the Borel set in $I\times I$

Comment: The Borel sets are only closed under countable union. If you take y to be an increasing sequence, the problem then is that your sets will be an countably infinite union of boxes, which I think won't be able to approximate all the shapes that the set could take.